# C# to Access - Inserting a ComboBox to Access column

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm not getting any errors and I'm a bit lost on where to look to solve the problem (my first project - Probably way over my head heh).  The Amount and Settlement amount both save to the table but the combobox options aren't saving.   The Access fields are set to Short Text (if that helps).

I'm not looking for a hand me out but rather if someone could point me in the right direction to get this solved.

```
        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            //converting data entered to be imported into Access tblePayments
            string EmployeeConverted;
            double AmountConverted;
            string ClientConverted;
            string PaymentMethodConverted;
            string PaymentTypeConverted;
            string MonthConverted;
            int SettlementConverted;

            EmployeeConverted = Convert.ToString(cboxEmployee.SelectedValue);
            AmountConverted = Convert.ToDouble(txtAmount.Text);
            ClientConverted = Convert.ToString(cboxClient.SelectedValue);
            PaymentMethodConverted = Convert.ToString(cboxPaymentMethod.SelectedValue);
            PaymentTypeConverted = Convert.ToString(cboxPaymentType.SelectedValue);
            MonthConverted = Convert.ToString(cboxMonth.SelectedValue);
            SettlementConverted = Convert.ToInt32(txtSettlement.Text);

            //inserting converted data into Access
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "insert into tblePayments (Employee, AmountofPayment, Client, PaymentMethod, PaymentType, MonthofPayment, Settlement) values('" + EmployeeConverted + "', " + AmountConverted + ", '" + ClientConverted + "', '" + PaymentMethodConverted + "', '" + PaymentTypeConverted + "', '" + MonthConverted + "', " + SettlementConverted + ")";

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Payment Saved");

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + error);
        }
```

Comment: But does the code execute? What happens when you debug and reach the command.ExecuteNonQuery(); line?

Comment: Yea,  the Amount and Settlement fields get added to the table in access.  Just not the combo box fields. No errors are showing up when I run it.

Comment: I've solved my problem.  I took out the convert.ToString and used cboxEmployee.Text.ToString() in the insert string and the data saved.